# Force at angles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors, geometry

[image: l]

I was trying to solve the question shown and realized the guy uses the cosine law. I haven't been at the top of the game for a while so had to google a bit more on the cosine law and I am pretty sure the last variables (12F^2cos(x)) is supposed to be a negative. I have tried to look for other related questions but don't trust most of the sites out there and most don't use the cosine rule to solve such problems. Could anybody guide me through the question using the cosine rule and alternatives methods are appreciated too. Do not hesitate to post alternative problems as I am interested in learning different methods.

Comment: Out of curiosity where did you get this example?  I think "magnetic" should be magnitude.

Comment: The more I read this problem the less sense it makes.  Are they stating that the resultant vector in the second case is twice that of the first case?  That is not obvious.

Comment: Sorry about that. It is indeed magnitude. It was on a youtube video and the person did correct it verbally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For vector analysis try to use vector algebra. The resultant vector for $\vec{P}$ and $\vec{Q}$ is given by $\vec{F}_{total}=\vec{P}+\vec{Q}$. So the magnitude of resultant force/vector will be $|\vec{F}_{total}|=\sqrt{\vec{F}_{total}^2}$
$$|\vec{F}_{total}|=\sqrt{\vec{F}_{total}\cdot\vec{F}_{total}}=\sqrt{(\vec{P}+\vec{Q}).(\vec{P}+\vec{Q})}$$
$$|\vec{F}_{total}|=\sqrt{\vec{P}^2+\vec{Q}^2+2\vec{P}\cdot\vec{Q}}=\sqrt{\vec{P}^2+\vec{Q}^2+2|\vec{P}||\vec{Q}|cos(\theta)}$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between two vectors.

Comment: This does not answer the question.  According to the work shown the OP knows this, they seem to be doing vector algebra correctly.

Comment: I believe the work show is not of OP's and some other guy, who according to OP used cosine rule. OP is asking for some alternative way to solve the problem so I am introducing them to vector algebra instead of cosine rule of triangles.

Comment: If I understand the question, and it is really badly worded, I think that the variable should be different on each side.  One gets a new theta that is a function of the old theta.  Vector algebra or not as presented it would give a theta that is fixed for both configurations, which violates the premise of the question.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer makes so much clear. It is the very formula being used which I must have confused for the cosine rule.

Comment: Actually you can derive the same formula using cosine rule also, if you make the vector diagram correctly.